# Why .vmodule/ui 's init() function not directory assigning?

Tags: vlang

I'm new to v.

in .vmodule/ui/lable.v

```
fn (mut l Label) init(parent Layout) {
    ui := parent.get_ui()
    l.ui = ui
}
```

What's differnce with

```
fn (mut l Label) init(parent Layout) {
    l.ui = parent.get_ui()
}
```

not only Label, others are same.

Why coding like that?

Answer (score 3):

This used to be a technical limitation of the language, directly assigning an interface to a struct field wasn't possible some times ago. It has now been fixed though ! There is no reason to keep this `ui` variable anymore